# Почему модальное окно всплывает только при втором клике на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, popup, modal

Есть несколько кнопок, которые должны вызывать модальное окно.  Каждая из них выглядит так

```
<a href="#" class="btn nav__btn" data-back="Click me" data-front="Get started" onclick="popup(this)"></a>
```

код

```
function popup(event)
{
    event.addEventListener('click', function(e){      
      e.preventDefault();
      popUp.classList.add('active');
      
      
      // чтобы закрывалось окно при нажатии на черное
      popUp.addEventListener('click', function(){
        popUp.classList.remove('active');
        
          
      }) 
      const closePopUp = document.getElementById('closePopUp');
      closePopUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
        popUp.classList.remove('active');
      } )
    })
}
```

Comment: Потому что по первому клику на кнопку вы навешиваете на неё слушатель нажатия на кнопку, который уже вызывает модальное окно. По второму клику срабатывает первый слушатель, и вы навешиваете на кнопку ещё один слушатель. По третьему клику сработают уже два навешенных слушателя, и будет навешен третий такой же. Ну и так далее.

Comment: спасибо!  А как можно это изменить, чтобы срабатывало правильно, не подскажете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="btn nav__btn" data-back="Click me" data-front="Get started" onclick="popup()"></a>
```

```
function popup()
{
      popUp.classList.add('active');
      return false;
}

// чтобы закрывалось окно при нажатии на черное
popUp.addEventListener('click', function(){
    popUp.classList.remove('active');
});
const closePopUp = document.getElementById('closePopUp');
closePopUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popUp.classList.remove('active');
});
```

Comment: Работает! спасибо вам большое!